# Azure API Management service with external virtual network to Docker

Tags: docker, azure-virtual-machine, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network, plumber

I want to use the Azure API Management Service (AMS) to expose the API created with `R/Plumber` hosted in a Docker container and runs in an Ubuntu machine.

#### Scenario

With `R/Plumber` I created some APIs that I want to protect. Then, I created a virtual machine on Azure with Ubuntu and installed Docker. The APIs are in a container that I published on the virtual machine by Docker. I can access them via internet.

On Azure I created an API Management service and added the APIs from the Swagger OpenAPI documentation.

[image]

#### Problem

I want to secure the APIs. I want to expose to the internet only the AMS. Then, my idea was to remove the public IP from the virtual machine and via a virtual network using the internal IPs to connect the API Management Service to the API with the internal IP (http://10.0.1.5:8000).

So, I tried to set a Virtual Network. Clicked on the menu, then External and then on the row, I can select a network. In this virtual network, I have one `network interface` that is the one the virtual machine is using.

[image]

When I save the changes, I have to wait a while and then I receive an error

> Failed to connect to management endpoint at azuks-chi-testapi-d1.management.azure-api.net:3443 for a service deployed in a virtual network. Make sure to follow guidance at https://aka.ms/apim-vnet-common-issues.

[image]

I read the following documentation but I can't understand how to do what I wanted

- [Azure API Management - External Type: gateway unable to access resources within the virtual network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060005/azure-api-management-external-type-gateway-unable-to-access-resources-within)
- [How to use Azure API Management with virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-common-network-configuration-issues)

Is there any how-to to use? Any advice? What are I doing wrong?

### Update

I tried to add more Address space in the Virtual network.

[image]

One of them (10.0.0.2/24) is delegate for the API Management.

[image]

Then, in the Network security group I added the port 3443.

[image]

From the API manager I can't reach the server with the internet IP (10.0.2.5). What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

See common network configuration issues, it lists all dependencies that are expected to be exposed for APIM to work. Make sure that your vnet allows ingress at port 3443 for the subnet where APIM service is located. This configuration must be done on VNET side, not APIM.